# Utilizar GET cuando url esta oculto con .htcacess

Tags: php, mvc, get, form-submit

Estoy usando php MVC (soy nuevo con MVC) y tengo archivo .htaccess en el cual tengo el siguiento codigo

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

tengo un controlador

```
class Enlaces{

    public function enlacesController(){

        if(isset($_GET["action"])){

            $enlaces = $_GET["action"];
        }else{

            $enlaces = "index";
        }

        $respuesta = EnlacesModels::enlacesModel($enlaces);
        include $respuesta;
    }
}
```

y un modelo

```
class EnlacesModels{

    public function enlacesModel($enlaces){

        switch ($enlaces) { 
            case 'captura':             
                $module = "vistas/modulos/padron/".$enlaces.".php";
                return $module;
                break;
            case 'inicio':
            case 'ingreso':
                $module = "vistas/modulos/".$enlaces.".php";        
                return $module;
                break;  
            case 'index':
                $module = "vistas/modulos/ingreso.php";     
                return $module;
                break;                                                                      
            default:
                $module = "vistas/modulos/ingreso.php";
                return $module;
                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

y tengo un formulario en donde quiero usar un GET, pero por lo anterior no me lo permite ya que la ruta oculta el action (que utilice en los controladores con un get anterior) y Meda la siguiente ruta (pone otro "?" en vez de "&"   )

http://localhost/caiga20/captura?search_apat=morghen&search_amat=&search_ife=

como puedo resolver eso????? Ayuda!!!

este es l codigo del formulario

```
  <div class="row">
      <form method="GET">
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">           
          <label for="search_apat"> A Paterno: </label>
          <input id="search_apat" name="search_apat" class="form-control search_apat" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <label for="search_amat"> A Materno: </label>
          <input id="search_amat" name="search_amat" class="form-control search_amat" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-10">
          <label for="search_ife"> Clave Elector: </label>
          <input id="search_ife" name="search_ife" class="form-control search_ife" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">                
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </a>
          </span>                                  
        </div>   
      </div>  
      </form>                  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

agregue al .htaccess las siguientes reglas

```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hola Rafa, ¿esta publicación es un intento de responder o un comentario/añadido a la pregunta? Si es lo primero, deberías poner algo más de información (p.e. ¿por qué soluciona esto el problema?); si es lo segundo, deberías añadirlo directamente en la pregunta pulsando en el botón de editar.

Comment: Como ya t han comentado, necesitas explicar la respuesta para que pueda ser más clara y tu respuesta sea candidata a ser aceptada

Comment: al parecer no es la respuesta adecuada, ya que me funciono de manera local  pero al subirlo al hosting funciona ... pero posteriormente sale este error      .htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: aun necesito ayuda con estoo